# Ubuntu Activities showing wrong name for an installed application?

Tags: gnome, java, eclipse, activities-overview

By default the windows title of my application in Ubuntu Activities Overview appears as `eclipse-jdt-internal-jarinjarloader-jarRsrcLoader`. This has nothing to do with the real name of my application except that it is written in Java and that the Jar file was created in eclipse. I want my application's real name to appear in the Activities as the window title. What should I do make this happen?

P.S: This is a commercial application and there are many clients for it as well. So the fix has to be dynamic such that it'll work in every system where the application gets installed.

Comment: In the activities overview, you are seeing the window titles. Thus, your application will need to set a proper window title. Or are you referring to the label of the icon in the Dock? Please clarify a little (use "edit").

Comment: Ask the provider of the application.

Comment: @SorenA I'm the provider.